# Angular directive closure issue compiling from scope variable

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope

I have a directive which compiles a template and uses a variable on scope to increment index values in the template.

Here is my directive:

```
angular.module('app').directive( 'ingredient', function ( $compile, persistedCount, $templateRequest) {


return {
    restrict: 'E',
    template: '<div sticky-nav><button type="button" class="btn btn-success" ng-click="add()">add ingredient  <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus" aria-hidden="true"></span> </button></div>',
    controller: function ( $scope, $element ) {
      $scope.ingredientNumber = persistedCount.ingredients = persistedCount.ingredients || 0;


  $scope.add = function () {

    $templateRequest("templates/ingredients-template.html").then(function(html){
        compileIngredients(html);   
    });

    function compileIngredients(html){
          $element.parent().append($compile(html)($scope));
          console.log($scope.ingredientNumber);
    }

    persistedCount.ingredients++;
    console.log(persistedCount.ingredients);


};
```

persistedCount Service:

```
angular.module('app').service('persistedCount',function(){
return{
    persistedCount:{
        ingredients: 0,
        directions:0,
        notes:0
      }
    }
});
```

I'm using one variable in my template `$scope.ingredientNumber`, really just to increment the index values like this.

```
<formly-form model="vm.model.data.ingredients[ingredientNumber].quantity" fields="vm.fields.data.ingredients[ingredientNumber].quantity"> </formly-form>
```

The problem is that the $scope.ingredientNumber never increases, but the persistedCount does. I think this is a closure issue? It seems like $scope.incrementNumber never picks up a new value after being set initially?

When I set `$scope.ingredientNumber = persistedCount.ingredients = persistedCount.ingredients || 0;` inside of the $scope.add function it incriments correctly but everything on the DOM picks up that value as well. So instead of having 0,1,2,3 I have 3,3,3,3

Answer (score 1):

This line is run only once according to your code the first time the controller is loaded:

```
$scope.ingredientNumber = persistedCount.ingredients = persistedCount.ingredients || 0;
```

So it seems there's a problem with your logic.

Side note: it is considered bad practice to manipulate the DOM via a controller. Are you sure you can't simplify your solution by creating a directive for an ingredient with the template you are loading and just use ng-repeat to display the list of ingredients?